# Replacing the value in between vectors when there is a defined difference

Tags: r, replace, diff

I have question on replacing the value in between the vectors.

The algorithm should find that replacement number when the certain condition is met. In this case finding the number which makes the difference -20 with the previous number. So I prefer to use `diff` function.

Here is what I mean

```
x <- c(20,20,0,20,0,5)
> diff(x)
[1]   0 -20  20 -20   5
```

So in this case `0` makes the difference -20 and I want to change those `0`s  to `20`.
. I know the easiest solution is the directly assigning `x[3] <- 20` or `x[5] <- 20`

However, the `0` location is always different so I need an automated process that can do that. Thanks!

**EDIT
if we need to do this in a grouped data.frame

```
> df
    x gr
1  20  1
2  20  1
3   0  1
4  20  1
5   0  1
6   5  1
7  33  2
8   0  2
9  20  2
10  0  2
11 20  2
12  0  2
```

How can we implement this ?

```
modify <- function(x){
  value_search = c(0, 33)
  value_replacement = c(20, 44)

  for (k in 1:length(value_search)) {
  index_position = which(x %in% value_search[k])
  replacement = value_replacement[k]
  for (i in index_position) {
    x[i] = replacement
  }
  }
}


df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(modif_x=modify(x))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'match' requires vector arguments.
```

Comment: @Sotos after finding the location how to replace them in automated way? Say you have many x vector in a grouped data.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a generic way to replace values of a vector based on particular values, i would approach it this way.

```
x = c(20,20,0,20,0,5)
value_search = 0
value_replacement = 20

index_position = which(x %in% value_search)
for (i in index_position) {
  x[i] = value_replacement
}
```

but this works for single values. if you want to look for multiple values, you can use a nested loop as below:

```
x = c(20,20,0,20,0,5,33)
value_search = c(0, 33)
value_replacement = c(20, 44)

for (k in 1:length(value_search)) {
  index_position = which(x %in% value_search[k])
  replacement = value_replacement[k]
  for (i in index_position) {
    x[i] = replacement
  }
}
```

in response to OP's edits:
any number of ways to do this:

```
x = c(20,20,0,20,0,5,33)
gr = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
df = data.frame(x, gr)

func_replace <- function(source, value_search, value_replacement) {
  for (k in 1:length(source)) {
    index_position = which(x %in% value_search[k])
    replacement = value_replacement[k]
    for (i in index_position) {
      source[i] = replacement
    } # for i loop
  } # for k loop
  return(source)
} # func_replace

value_search = c(0, 33)
value_replacement = c(20, 44)
gr_value = 1

df$replacement = with(df, ifelse(gr == gr_value, sapply(df, FUN = function(x) func_replace(x, value_search, value_replacement)), NA))
```

Comment: could use *apply + function but for small vectors, this should be plenty performant

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can we implement your for loop inside to function and apply to a `data.frame`? I tried some but it didn't worked out.Could you check OP ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by grouped data? are the replacement values different by group?

Comment: Yes there is also condition in my real data that only gr==1 should be replaced. That;s what I meant.

Comment: i think this should work. certainly not the most elegant. i had a similar situation not to long ago

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `which` to get the position, i.e.

```
x[which(diff(x) == -20)+1] <- 20
x
#[1] 20 20 20 20 20  5
```